# navbar-btn and navbar-toggle issues with Bootstrap

Tags: html, navbar

I just followed the tutsplus lesson on the navbar (https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/courses/bootstrap-3-for-web-design/lessons/the-navbar). As far as I can tell, my code is near enough identical to his, and yet I'm having some problems. If I try to create a button using the  element, anything following is pushed to a new line.

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example-nav">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-nav">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        </ul>

        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">This is a button</a>

        <p class="navbar-text">Hello!</p>

        <form action="" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>  

    </div>
  </div>
```

Also, nothing happens when I click on the navbar-toggle button at the top, when it should display all of the items on the navbar.

I have been trying to figure out how to fix it for hours and can't come up with a solution. Some people have said you shouldn't use an  element within a navbar, but the instructor does and it works fine for him.

I'm really struggling here, can anyone figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

I actually think I've figured it out now, but I'll leave this here so others can learn from my mistake.
As far as I can tell, the problem wasn't in the code, I just wasn't linking my html to jQuery, or the bootstrap javascript (I'm very new to it all).

So I added

```
    <script src="../../../jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

within my head element (the link to my downloaded jquery, you could also link to the online version) and

```
    <script src="../../../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

to my body, just before the closing tag (again, this is my downloaded copy, use your own, or the online version). Everything now runs as I hoped it would.